# angular js file saver use for export from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filesaver.js

I have used file saver from below

bower install angular-file-saver --save

for have passed json string also in below code instead of get innerhtml like below,

```
$scope.items = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    email: "j.smith@example.com",
    dob: "1985-10-10"
  }, {
    name: "Jane Smith",
    email: "jane.smith@example.com",
    dob: "1988-12-22"
  }];
```

but it not worked and print json string in single column in exported file

```
 var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
            });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

my html code for datatable is

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div id='exportable' ng-controller="getDataTable as showCase">
                <table class="table table-bordered" datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="row-border hover"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using datatable in "exportable" id

how to work with export to excel with file saver and datatable?

here with datatble it is exported with page selected and pagination ,I want only table

can any one help me to resolve it

Comment: Can you post your html code also ?

Comment: thanks for quick response,I have updated my question for html code

Comment: You are using server side pagination that means you only be able to  export 10 rows at a time into excel.

Comment: yes,that is fine ,10 records are comming in export,but  it possible to pass json string instead of pass html in export code?

Comment: Is your table is displaying a data ?

Comment: yes, records are comming with datatable

Answer (score 1):

first create two div in html like following and create a link:

```
   <a ng-click="exportDataInExcel()">Export</a>
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div ng-controller="getDataTable as showCase">
          <table class="table table-bordered" datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="row-border hover"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-12" hidden>
       <div ng-controller="getDataTable as showCase" id='exportable'>
          <table class="table table-bordered" datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" dt-instance="showCase.dtInstance" class="row-border hover"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and int your controller create a function like following:

```
$scope.exportDataInExcel = function(){
    var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML],{
      type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
}
```

Comment: it will not worked ,it give me excel file with datatable page filter dropdown,pagination ,page show ,that is not required in export,I required only table data

Comment: So you need to assign your data in a scope an then use ng-repeat on that scope.

Comment: that I have done,but it is repetitive ,is is possible to use json string instead of use html table structure

Comment: Great ! You have to use table structure because according to table structure it will generate the cell structure of excel file.